# Converting named parameters to GET parameters for pagination at CakePHP 2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I am trying to convert named parameters to GET parameters for pagination at CakePHP  2.2 following the instructions given in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#using-get-parameters-for-pagination) but it is not working.

Instead of this:

```
http://localhost/cake/posts/yourPosts/page:2?url=posts%2FyourPosts
```

I want this:

```
http://localhost/cake/posts/yourPosts/?page=2&url=posts%2FyourPosts
```

The thing is, when i submit a form using GET method, i don't want to retain the current page, and currently, it is doing it by default because it is not a normal param but a named param.

(*?url=posts%2FyourPosts* is added automatically with the GET method)

I have tried to to this in my view but it stills passing the parameter as a named one:

```
$this->Paginator->options(array('convertKeys' => array('page')));

echo $this->Paginator->next(' >', array('class' => 'button next right'), null, array('class' => 'next button'));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should fix the issue at its source, not cloaking it:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#pagination-with-get-parameters

```
public $paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);
```

in your controller

Comment: Thanks. It worked! Btw, is there anyway to apply it for all $this->paginate calls inside an action instead of having to add it one by one?

Comment: by using the above statement you automatically assign it to all (since its in the global controller scope).

Comment: It doesn't work for me that way. I have that on the controller but inside the function i have another $this->paginate and if i dont put it inside this last one it doesn't work, as well as the limit.

Comment: don't overwrite it this way then. use `$this->paginate['key'] = $foo;`. This way the previously defined keys will stay intact. basic PHP

Comment: Then it changes completely the way to write it. Mmm i think i prefer to repeat it in all paginates rather than having to rewrite all of them. Thanks.

Comment: For more details see [passed-named-or-query-string-params](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/)