# CakePHP 2.3: Change of pagination links

Tags: cakephp, pagination

currently my paginator links look like this:

```
if(isset($results) && count($results)){
   if($this->Paginator->hasPrev('Objekt')) echo $this->Paginator->prev($this->Html->image('pag_left.png', array('border' => 0, 'tag'=>'li', 'alt' => 'Vorheriges Objekt')), array('escape'=>false, 'tag'=>'li'));
                    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'tag'=>'li'));
                    if($this->Paginator->hasNext('Objekt')) echo $this->Paginator->next($this->Html->image('pag_right.png', array('border' => 0, 'tag'=>'li', 'alt' => 'Nächstes Objekt')), array('escape'=>false, 'tag'=>'li'));
                }
```

what outputs the following html:

```
<li class="current">1</li>
<li>
<a href="/objekts/search/page:2">2</a>
</li>
<li class="next">
<a href="/objekts/search/page:2">
</li>
```

How can I change it now to get instead links like:

> /use-the-current-URL/?page:2

I want to change from var:value to ?page=2

Please advice, what should I do?

Thanks!

---

Update: 
Still can't fix that...

I added `public $paginate = array( 'paramType' => 'querystring' );` to my Controller.

I added `var $paginate = array( 'paramType' => 'querystring' );` to my Model.

But still when I call `debug($this->Paginator->params())`; from my view it says that

> 'paramType' => 'named'

I even addin AppController beforeFilter()

```
$this->paginate['paramType'] = 'querystring';
```

... I am getting so mad with this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting named parameters to GET parameters for pagination at CakePHP 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007777/converting-named-parameters-to-get-parameters-for-pagination-at-cakephp-2-2)

Comment: it says to add 

public $paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring'
);

to the controller where I do the pagination. I tried this (thanks for the reference link) but it's not changing anything...

Comment: A complete summary on how to properly switch to query strings completely is also to be found [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/)

Comment: I know this link, I therefore added the link into my AppController into beforeFilter function... but this was not helping me...